# How would you diagram "He delights in his toys"

Tags: grammar, diagramming

Settling a friendly argument: The sentence "He delights in his toys" seems to me to diagram with "in his toys" as an adverbial from the verb "delights". How would you diagram this and why?

Comment: I don't have an answer (especially since my diagramming knowledge is pretty limited), but it strikes the issue is that we have a phrasal verb "delight in." It's not just a prepositional phrase, like "He walks in the field."

Comment: *To delight in* is not a phrasal verb. (S (NP He)
   (VP delights
       (PP in
           (NP his toys.)))) It is identical, grammatically to "He walks in the field." OED: 1b. intransitive. **To give great pleasure or enjoyment to people; to be a cause or source of delight.** -- 1340   Ayenbite (1866) 91   *Þe lostuolle guodes of þe wordle guoþ in-to þe herte uor to deliti.* -- 1904   L. T. Meade Love Triumphant v   *I mean to go to London..to meet my equals. I shall dazzle, I shall delight.*

Comment: @Greybeard I'm not sure that's the same usage. My OE isn't up to snuff, but I'm pretty sure both examples equate to "it delights," a sort of intransitive-that-implies-a-transitive. But the OP's example seems like a transitive phrasal verb, as covered [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delight%20in) and [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/delight-in)

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes but [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/delight) does not consider this a phrasal verb, and the complement of the preposition is not an object. Moreover it is difficult to conceive this complement as the object since sth can only delight a person.

Comment: @LPH Sorry, maybe I'm gleaning something different from the lexico entry, but my takeaway is that adding "in" allows you to reverse the syntax: "His toys delight him" -> "He delights in his toys." I don't feel confident at the moment about asserting what is an object here and what isn't. I'm not sure how it affects anything, but it seems that "he delights in" is equivalent to "he *takes* delight in"...

Comment: @AndyBonner Still, in this last construction "delight" is the object.

Comment: It's not a phrasal verb because it doesn't alternate. _Delight_ is normally intransitive as a verb, but it can express the source of the delight with a prepositional phrase using _in_. That's if the person experiencing the delight is the subject. If, on the other hand, the source of the delight is the subject, then the verb is transitive, and the experiencer is the direct object. As for diagramming, it's verb plus prepositional phrase, which is not hard to diagram.

Comment: @Greybeard , AndyBonner As John demonstrates "delight in" is not a so-called phrasal verb: "He delights his toys in" is ungrammatical. However, this does not mean that the *in*-preposition phrase is not a Complement of the verb *delight*. It is. The claim that this sentence has the structure of "He walks in the field" is incorrect. To wit, "He walks every Thursday" is fine. "He delights every Thursday" is questionable, but ok in the right context. However, note a) no context is needed for *walk* b) the meaning of *delight* is reversed: in OP's example the toys do the delighting.

Comment: For some people, _delight in_ would be a transitive V+P combination, like _look at_ and _listen to_ (which would make the object of the P an object), while for other people it would be a simple V with a PrepP following and no object. Not everybody has the same grammar, you know; everybody makes up their own.

Comment: Clearly, *He delights in his toys* is a different construction than *He poops in his pants*. Look up "prepositional verb" for ideas.

Comment: "In" is a preposition so "in his toys" is a PP (preposition phrase), here probably functioning as an adjunct (your adverbial). I say 'probably' because some would regard the PP as a complement on the grounds that "delights" selects the preposition "in" for this particular meaning.

Comment: @Greybeard 'It is identical, grammatically to "He walks in the field." ' No; no matter what terminology you use, 'delight in' is far more cohesive than 'walk .. in'. //// 'He walks in / over / through / across / around / by / to / past ... the field.' // 'He delights _**in**_ his toys. //// One can query the term 'phrasal verb' most dictionaries seem to apply to the colligation 'delight in', but the very fact that they list the string shows that they acknowledge a stronger cohesion than with 'walk in'.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely verb + prepositional phrase, for reasons given by commentators.

Comment: I very much dislike the term 'phrasal verb'. since it implies that the verb+prep form a verb. They don't. In, for example "They fell out, it's not the whole expression that is a verb, but just the word "fell". The term 'verbal idiom' is more appropriate, since it doesn't distort the syntax.

Comment: @BillJ the preposition is not really a preposition, it is a particle often acting adverbially. e.g.  "They fell out" tells you more about how they fell... "They fell outwards." "They fell out of the box" "They fell outwards(adv-motion) {from the box(PP/adv - place)}" In many cases, the "preposition" can be seen as an abbreviated form with an assumed object noun, and, together, these create the adverbial PP -> I pushed it {**up** [the chimney]}.

Comment: @Greybeard 'Particle' is not a part of speech but a general term to describe those prepositions that can occur between a verb and its direct object, as well as occurring after the object, as in "She brought **down** the suitcase" ~ "She brought the suitcase **down**", where in both cases the preposition "down" is a particle by virtue of being able to occur between the verb and its object as well as after the object. There are also one or two adjectives and verbs that can be particles.

Comment: @Greybeard In "They fell out", "out" is a prep functioning as locative complement of "fell". It's a complement, not an adjunct (your adverbial), because it is obligatory for this sense of "fell", which means roughly "fell down quickly”, as opposed to "disagree".

Comment: @Greybeard The point I was trying to make in my first comment was that in, for example, "They fell out" the sequence "fell out" is not a constituent at word level: it’s a VP. Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s "fell" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have "They had fallen out" but not *"They had fall outed".

Comment: All right, I have eliminated my question, and just left my answer, even though the question is answered by to an existing other "commentaries".  My problem is if I ask a question which is related string, people say I should delete the question, but I can't comment on other strings until I get 50 points.

Comment: @BillJ I used "phrasal verb," although I see many on this site using "multi-word verb", and I saw several commentators above using the traditional term.  The problem with "verbal idiom" is that "idiom" does not necessarily mean "more than one word", which is the key feature we are trying to name.  "Thou shalt not change traditional terminology" is my motto.  As to disputes about what is an adverb, preposition, or particle, the historical development of Greek shows these are fluid concepts.  A good definition of "adverb" is: "define nouns, verbs, etc.  Anything left over is an adverb."

Comment: The term ‘multi-word verb’ is just as misleading as the term ‘phrasal verb’, since again it implies that the two words combine to form a single lexeme, which they don’t. Compare: “They fell out” (“argued”) in which "fell out” is a constituent. But it is not a constituent at word level: it’s a VP. Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s fell that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have “They had fallen out”, but not *”They had fall outed”.

Comment: French people believe that there is no inflection of English verbs apart from -s on the 3rd sing pres simple, and -ed on the end of the past simple.  The only inflection on "had fallen" is on the auxiliary verb "had".  Other people, myself included, would say that the verb "fall" is being inflected here, by virtue of the inflection of the auxiliary verb, and that the definition of "word" as "whatever bits of language are spelled with white space around them" is not good.  The words "tmesis"